# How to import Spring application context from another maven module?

Tags: java, spring, maven, multi-module

I have two modules in my project which are children of the main **app.pom**

```
<modules>
    <module>commons</module>
    <module>webapp</module>
</modules>
```

The **webapp** module refers to **commons** this way:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.app.whatever</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

The **commons** module is just packaged in .jar file and that's it. All their dependencies **webapp** and **commons** inherit from **app.pom**.
Both **commons** and **webapp** use Spring 3 with .xml files that describe application contexts.
In **webapp** module I want to use a bean from **commons** module. Here's applicationContext for **commons**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.app.whatever.anything"/>
</beans>
```

For **webapp** applicationContext.xml I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

<import resource="classpath*:/applicationContext-commons.xml"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.app.whatever.something.controller.spring"/>
```

But unfortunately this  doesn't work. Constantly get an exception about no candidates for autowiring, though I can use any classes from the second module in the first one after setting the above maven dependency.
When I write this import without asterisk, it says that the file doesn't exist.
I tried without leading slash - the same exception.

This import works perfectly for any file from the same module and even for external libraries I have. But it can't resolve the file from this new **commons** module I've just created.

If you have any idea, that'd be really helpful, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not under a subdirectory, e.g. `spring/applicationContext-commons.xml` then the following (which you've already tried) should work:

```
<import resource="classpath*:applicationContext-commons.xml"/>
```

With an asterisk, Spring will use all matching files on the classpath, without the asterisk it will use the first one it finds.

Also, with the asterisk Spring will ignore the file if it wasn't found. Without the asterisk Spring will give an error if it can't find the file. Therefore your file is not on the classpath.

I'd check the location of `applicationContext-commons.xml` under the `target` folder to make sure `<import resource=` has the correct path and re-run `mvn install` from the root pom.

Comment: You're right. I checked the location of the file, and it wasn't included in the resulting .jar file, because it was placed in /webapp folder, not /resources.